# How do I find the n-th Fourier coefficient of a function?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to define the function `f`:

- π for x ∈ (-1,1)
- 0 for all the others.

How do I  find the n-th coefficient of this function in the Fourier series expansion for (-3π, 3π)?

Comment: Is this a question about the computing software *Mathematica*? In that case, look up the functions `Piecewise` and `Integrate` in the documentation for proper syntax for defining piecewise-defined function and how to integrate functions. If not, perhaps you meant to ask this on [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

Define the function,

```
f[x_] := If[x < 1 && x > -1, \[Pi], 0]
```

or

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{\[Pi], x > -1 && x < 1}}, 0]
```

Do the series expansion, `b=1/3` for the required region $(-3\pi,3\pi)$ (check documentation of FourierSeries and FourierParameters) for details, here choosing `a=0`, and up to the 30th order

```
fx = FourierSeries[f[x], x, 30, FourierParameters -> {0, 1/3}];
```

You may plot it to see the approximation

```
Plot[fx, {x, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and to collect the terms by order, use

```
fxc = Collect[fx, E^((I x)/3) ]
```

> 1/3 + E^(-((I x)/3)) Sin[1/3] + E^((I x)/3) Sin[1/3] +   1/2 E^(-((2 I
>   x)/3)) Sin[2/3] + 1/2 E^((2 I x)/3) Sin[2/3] +   1/3 E^(-I x) Sin[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac8sY.png) +
>   1/3 E^(I x) Sin[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac8sY.png)+... (truncated)

where you may then access each one by array index e.g. `fxc[[3]]` (notice the grouping of negative and positive n)

Comment: Okay, but I have to make the draw of expansion of Fourier series of n-th order in (-3π,3π). How am I suppose to do that? n=1,3,5,7...15

Comment: @Crunchips something like `Plot[fxc[[3]] // ReIm // Evaluate, {x, -3 \[Pi], 3 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: Why is there a difference in FourrierParamers in in our answers? Did you look in Mma help?

Comment: @user64494 `FourierSeries` gives the whole series expansion, `FourierCoefficient` outputs the coefficient before the $n$-th order $e^{int}$, so there's actually no difference. notice for the whole expansion, the `n` in `FourierCoefficient ` goes from negative "cut" $-n_c$ to the positive $n_c$

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{\[Pi], x > -1 && x < 1}}, 0];
FourierCoefficient[f[x], x, n, FourierParameters -> {1, 1/3}] // TeXForm
```

> $$ \begin{cases}
>  \frac{1}{3} & n=0 \\
>  \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n}{3}\right)}{n} & \text{True}
> \end{cases} $$

See Mathematica help to `FourierCoefficient` for more info.